Unable to install MySQL on my machine
I am getting the error below while installing MySQL on my machine:
Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ noble-pgdg: /usr/share/postgresql-common/pgdg/apt.postgresql.org.asc != /usr/share/postgresql-common/pgdg/apt.postgresql.org.gpg

I'm getting this error when running sudo apt update.

This question is similar to: "Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source". If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

you can not install mysql using a link to POSTGRES
